# Android update overlayitem with changing locations

Tags: android

I have a set of objects which are displayed on the map. I am using ItemizedOverlay for this.
 But, the objects keep moving and I get their location updates each time. How can I update the fresh location for each object in my ItemizedOverlay. I need to refresh the locations of the objects regularly.

Can someone please suggest a good way to this.

Thank you,
Divya.

Answer (score 0):

Also looking how to accomplish this right way. At moment it have implemented it fallowing way.

I read that mapView.getOverlays() returns list which I can modify runtime.

> The list of overlays. This has been run through Collections.synchronizedList(java.util.List); thus feel free to query it or modify it as you see fit and the changes will be reflected on the next draw or event.

I got mine thing working when just removing overlays's before I am putting them back with add(). I suppose you are calling after every update part of the code which puts overlays into mapview

```
mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

mapOverlays.removeAll(mapOverlays);
```

before calling

```
mapOverlays.add(OverlayItem item);
```

I think there is no method to update existing points on map other than removing and adding them back via mapOverlays.add(OverlayItem item);